ToggleButton weird border color on over?
I'm using this StackPanel, with 3 ToggleButton:
<StackPanel x:Name="LanguageBoxAuth"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,280,0,0">
    <ToggleButton Content="IT"
                  Click="OnLanguageButtonAuth_Click" />
    <ToggleButton Content="EN"
                  Click="OnLanguageButtonAuth_Click" />
    <ToggleButton Content="ES"
                  Click="OnLanguageButtonAuth_Click" />
</StackPanel>

That's the style:
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="35" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="5,3" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="14" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Orange" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Orange" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Orange" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Orange" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

Which correctly display as:

But, when I over with mouse (ES in the example), a strange "gray" border appears:

Also, if I change window, a dotten one is introduced:

How can i remove the two? Removing dotted (of course) and keep Black also on over?
Note, I'm using MahApps.Metro alongside, which could override some properties I guess?

@Clemens can't use so properties directly on the xaml for the control? Why IsMouseOver is not sufficient? Can you help me to get this?

To get rid of the dots, you could set the FocusVisualStyle to null in yoyr Style:
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
...

The mouse over border colour can be set using the ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush attached property:
<Setter Property="mah:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush" Value="Black" />


Pretty nice! Seems to works perfect! Why doing this on Button (instead of ToggleButton) have no effect? I mean adding Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" and Setter property on Backround won't override it. Let me know if you need a new question (I can open it).

It depends on how the ControlTemplate is defined.

Its simple 



That's not the template.

I don't have any custom template, just integrated this way (as I did with ToggleButton, overriding the properties).

But there always is a default template applied.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
